# SELECT FLOOR RAND

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question:

```
$offset_result = mysql_query( " SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` `".$slug."_movie`");
$offset_row = mysql_fetch_object( $offset_result );
$offset = $offset_row->offset;
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `".$slug."_movie` LIMIT $offset, 10 " );
```

How to add the condition: Where STATUS=1 ?

To count only published movies..

now it has all :/

Someone will give an example?

Comment: is that even a question ?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$result = mysql_query( " SELECT * FROM `".$slug."_movie` WHERE STATUS=1 LIMIT $offset, 10 " );
```